# How to get the whole queryset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model called PostForum

```
class PostForum(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='forum_likes', blank=True)
```

In my class based view I have following code

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'forum/forum_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=self.object.id)
    posts = PostForum.objects.filter(category=category)
    context['posts'] = posts,
    return context
```

In template I cant reach posts title or content. I shows nothing

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {{post.title}}
   <p>{{post.content}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

when I render {{post}} to see the whole queryset 
 it shows

```
<QuerySet [<PostForum: My first post>]>
```

How to reach posts' title or content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a minor error in your `get_context_data` function which is causing this issue. Remove the trailing `,` from the `context['posts'] = posts,` line, so `get_context_data` should read:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=self.object.id)
    posts = PostForum.objects.filter(category=category)
    context['posts'] = posts  # remove the trailing comma from this line
    return context
```

There is no need to change your template.

For context, the trailing comma is turning `context['posts']` into a single element tuple, whose only element is the `posts` queryset, i.e. `context['posts'] = (posts,)`. So when you do `{% for post in posts %}` in your template you are not iterating over each `PostForm` in the queryset but rather each element in the tuple. Since there is only one element in the tuple, you are getting the entire `posts` queryset bound to the `post` loop variable one time instead of each `PostForum` instance bound to `post`.

Comment: Trailing commas in python are nasty!

Comment: Agreed! As is expecting `t = (1)` to be a single-element tuple ;)